# In Javascript or jQuery, how do I remove only the first and last tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

given the following string:

```
var htmlStr = '<p class="red_349dsa01">This is</p><p class="blue_saf9vsaz">a test</p>';
```

how can I remove the very first and last tag off this string?  This would be the result:

```
var htmlStr = 'This is</p><p class="blue_saf9vsaz">a test';
```

I know this will create invalid HTML, but I just want to know if this can be done at all.

Comment: Do you really need to do that?
Jquery has a great support to manipulate HTML but only if you use valid HTML, for example its very easy to just get the first paragraph

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like

```
var htmlStr = '<p class="red_349dsa01">This is</p><p class="blue_saf9vsaz">a test</p>';
alert(htmlStr.substring(htmlStr.indexOf('>') + 1, htmlStr.lastIndexOf('<')));
```

Comment: I always like to see a non-regex option, but after all the splitting, reversing, rejoining and string searching, would this be any faster?

Comment: It was the only reverse implementation I found. Many languages has built in string reversing, and i find that the easiest way to find a last reference, unless the language implemets indexOf with negative searching.

Comment: Found it, funny enoug, it was **lastIndexOf**. Sorry, that seems a lot easier.

Comment: lol yeah. It didn't occur to me you could just swap it all for lastIndexOf, I must be getting slow. I would +1 but I've run out of votes for today.

Answer (score 2):

You would need a regular expression here:

```
var regex = /(?:^<p[^>]*>)|(?:<\/p>$)/g;
var htmlStr = '<p class="red_349dsa01">This is</p><p class="blue_saf9vsaz">a test</p>';  
htmlStr.replace(regex, "");
```

An explanation of the regex:

1. The first part `(?:^<p[^>]*>)` uses the caret `^` character to match the start of the string,
2. then `<p` will match the start of the opening `p` tag,
3. `[^>]*` will match any character except the `>` character,
4. the `|` splits the expression into two, one in each pair of braces where either can be matched,
5. the `<\/p>$` expression will match a closing `</p>` tag *only* if it is right at the end of the string by using the `$` character.